# Will gpu be still used for training if I don't transfer tensor and model to gpu using to(device)?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab, and I need to know if it uses any GPU for training if I don't do model.to('cuda') and data.to('cuda')?

Comment: No, it won't use any GPU resources if you didn't specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not use `model.to(torch.device('cuda'))` and `data.to(torch.device('cuda'))` your model and all of your tensors will be remaining on default device which is **CPU**, so they do not understand the existence of **GPU**. PyTorch uses **CPU** for its work.

You can see this [Link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch.torch.device) for more information about torch.device.